# Getting taxis in Stockholm, Helsinki, Oslo and Copenhagen

Tags: taxis, cph, hel, arn, osl

Would like to know how to ensure a cab right at the airports of all Scandinavian nations. What currency is accepted by the drivers in cash in all 4 capitals?

Thanks.

Comment: This is four separate questions. Answers for all of them may be different and people might not know the answer to all of them. Stack Exchange doesn't work well in situations where there are partial answers.

Answer (score 4):

As at any other major airport, you can simply walk out of the terminal and catch a taxi. You can only expect the taxi drivers to accept local currency and it may even be difficult to get change for larger bills. In all Scandinavian countries, card payments are much too common for taxi drivers to have plenty of change.

At least in Oslo and Stockholm, you will arrive much faster and cheaper in the city centre if you go by train.

Comment: Having visited both recently, Copenhagen and Helsinki also have fast and fairly cheap direct train connections into the city centre

Comment: If you're going to the exact city center in Copenhagen, the train is indeed a better choice. Taxis may still be more convenient if your destination is not on one of the train or metro lines from the airport. Also about ten times the cost, though.

Comment: @etmuse It is of course possible to get to the city centre in Copenhagen and Helsinki with public transport. The airports are however much closer to the city than in Oslo and Stockholm and I would expect that most places in the city can be reached faster with a taxi, unless you are going somewhere in the immediate vicinity of a train station on a direct line from the airport. Saving some time and not having to carry your luggage around on public transport may for many be worth the extra price for a taxi in Copenhagen or Helsinki.